# How to send notification when node similar to flagged one is posted

Tags: flags, notifications

I want to send notifications to the user when a new node similar to one he has flagged is posted.

Comment: What do you mean by similar nodes ? Based on what condition you are meaning it similar ?

Comment: By similar i mean if the new node has same values as the flagged one by the user e.g city, location, price.

Answer (score 0):

You need to user [RULES](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module to achieve this functionality. Drupal flag module has full integration with rules modules.

By creating a rule saying condition is "Node is flagged" add an action saying "Send email to author of node."

Comment: Your answer does not explain how to identify similar types of nodes.

Comment: Hi, I want to send mail after comparing the values of new node to the node that has been flagged by the user e.g city, location, price. I tried to to it with Data comparison in rules but dont see relative token values for flagged node.